# New to ubuntu and want to install vlc

Tags: software-installation, vlc

I do not know why Ubuntu Software Center does not download VLC for me. when i click on VLC player it displays a pop-up and says

```
**Package Dependencies can not be resolved**
"This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are
 missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between 
 software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time."
```

Comment: Please open a terminal window (e. g. `gnome-terminal`), run the command `sudo apt-get install vlc`, and report back with the output of that command. From that we should know more about the cause of the issue. Also please [edit] your question if you provide that command output or any other additional info, because it's a lot easier to have everything in one place than scattered throughout the comment section.

Comment: Tried `sudo apt-get install vlc` in terminal window but at the end it says **Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages**.

Comment: run `apt-cache policy vlc` & post. Maybe you added a ppa?

Comment: @SayedFakhirShah: That's a start. Run `sudo apt-get install -f` to try to fix the held broken packages issue (or get more info on what's wrong) and post its output – the whole output this time please. You can select and copy terminal content with the mouse pointer.

Comment: `diyan@Shah-G:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
diyan@Shah-G:~$ 
`

Answer (score 0):

try out `sudo apt-get install vlc`. Using apt-get can be more reliable than the software center sometimes

Comment: This is pretty much what software center does behind the curtains. The benefit of going directly through `apt-get` is, that we can see its output including any error messages.

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get install vlc` but it says **Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages**

Comment: @SayedFakhirShah: Run `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean` and then try `sudo apt-get install vlc`.

Comment: Run those but the same problem

Answer (score -2):

Try doing a fresh install of vlc. `sudo apt-get remove vlc`. Then `sudo apt-get install vlc`.

Comment: I tried this way and it gives me the same message **Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages**